# Cleanup Storage files

Tags: c#, msmq, resource-cleanup

I have a C# application based on MSMQ to have a persistent queue on a local pc. I am using MSMQ locally and not to send messages cross network.

My problem is that i do not have a huge hard drive, and in certain conditions the MSMQ storage files are too many and they are filling all the available disk space.

Also if I purge the queue, the files are still there.

I checked on the web and found this solution using MSMQApplication.Tidy.
Here the link --> [Link to MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/12/19/forcing-msmq-to-clean-up-its-storage-files.aspx)

However I am not able to use it inside my c# application, I do not find the related COM object.

Other possible way is to change the registry key MessageCleanupInterval, but this not feed my need.
I need to clean up the queue when I want.

Comment: you may want to see if you can use WMI to do the same thing as per the link and use the Management classes in .NET to execute the code.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".